# SQL query in Access update multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS Access, can I run multiple UPDATE statements in one SQL query?

Say I have a table with columns A-F.
What I want to do is this:

```
UPDATE table SET C = NULL WHERE C = 0
UPDATE table SET D = NULL WHERE D = 0
UPDATE table SET E = NULL WHERE E = 0
```

I understand that with SQL Server I could use a 'GO' after each line but that doesn't seem to work with Access.  Is there an alternative, or do I just have to run a load of separate queries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET 
  C=IIF(C=0,NULL,C),
  D=IIF(D=0,NULL,D),
  E=IIF(E=0,NULL,E)
WHERE
  C=0 OR D=0 OR E=0
```

Comment: This is a correct answer to your question. But an added note just case you or someone else reading this sees it, you can only update one table at a time.